# why can't kernel access user process address directly

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

This article https://lwn.net/Articles/75174/

says that if the kernel wants to access a physical page, it needs to map it to a linear address in the kernel space (to high memory region).

Suppose the page is already mapped by an user process, can the kernel just use the user-process page table to access that page directly (since they share the same page table)? Why does the kernel have to map it again?

Comment: If a page is mapped in user-space it probably lacks the appropriate permissions (bits set in page table entry) and thus a new mapping is required.

Comment: you mean the S/U bit? if the CPU is on supervisor (ring 0), can it not read/execute data/instruction in ring 3?

Comment: I believe when CPL=0, all pages are addressable

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose the page is already mapped by an user process, can the kernel just use the user-process page table to access that page directly (since they share the same page table)?

Yes, after you checking [if the userspace-supplied pointer is valid](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h#L98), you could dereference it. The kernel has `copy_(to|from)_user` helpers that encapsulate this.

> Why does the kernel have to map it again?

Normally, when you need to fiddle with *physical* addresses, say for interacting with memory mapped devices, you won't find the page already mapped in userspace. If it's not within the low memory region you have page tables for, you'll have to map them.

Note, that with 64-bit systems, this is not a concern any longer, as you've enough bits for everything to be low memory.

Comment: does it (mapping the page in kernel space) also happen when the user space process wants more memory to be allocated? In any case, why can't the kernel just directly modify the user-process part of the page table, instead of mapping it to the kernel space?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. If the kernel wants a mapping, it will usually not make it accessible to userspace. And if userspace requests a mapping (e.g. via `mmap`), the kernel will make it accessible to userspace.